# iOS : Send invitation to facebook friends

Tags: ios, facebook, invitation

I am using Facebook SDK to connect `Facebook` in my app.  User will logged in once and will make invitation about `MyApp` to their friends. I am successful to get `ids` and `name` of all Facebook friends. But I couldn't access to email id of Facebook friends. **Is there anyway to get access to Facebook friends email ids?** So that I can send them a invitation email.

**Is there any other ways, that I can accomplish invitation function in application.** 
I hourly searched on `google` and `so` but no results points me to the solution.

**Edit:**
I've already accepted an answer, that says, there's no ways to get access to friends email id's. So I am looking for some other solution. There should be some solution exist.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Unless they make their emails public

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can get all the email ids of your Facebook friends. But if you have any concept like "Buddies" or "Friends" in your app, you can send request to the mail ids of registered users of your app who is already your Facebook friend. This is how many social network apps like Instagram do.

**'Find Friends via Facebook' functionality in Instagram** lists out the user's Facebook friends who are already on Instagram.

Eg: A and B are 2 users who are registered on Instagram. A and B are Facebook friends. But A & B are not buddies on Instagram.

While availing 'Find Friends via Facebook' facility, Instagram fetches user's Facebook-email-ID, Facebook-ID etc. Facebook provides API in such a way that user can list out his friends ID. Now, match-making is made to check if any of friend's Facebook-ID is already registered with Instagram. Thus it lists out all the facebook friends of users who are already registered with Instagram so that user can add him/her to the user's buddy-list.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for?

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-games/requests/